# Is there a way to dynamically select values from YAML front matter in Grav using twig templates?

Tags: templates, dynamic, twig, grav, yaml-front-matter

I am working with Grav and trying to dynamically select a specific array to use from a config variable based on the current active language. I know I can use if and else if statements, but I would rather not do that because each time another array is added as an option, conditional block will grow in size.

I know that in Grav I can use `{{~grav.language.getActive~}}` to print the currently active language, but I would like to use that value as another part of a Grav variable. For example,

Say my config file is called video, is stored in user\config\, and looks like this:

```
error: 
  en: "This is an error."
  es: "Esto es un error."
```

I would like to access the value error.(active_language_here).

I have tried:

- `{{ config.video.error.{{~grav.language.getActive~}} }}` which has an error saying: Expected name or number.
- `{{attribute(config.video.error, Language->getActive())}}` which has an error saying: Unexpected token "operator" of value ">"

If you need any more information, please let me know! Thank you for the help!

Is there a way to do this in Grav as of right now?

Comment: Don't use `->` in twig, it's always `.`, e.g. `{{ attribute(config.video.error, Language.getActive()) }}`

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the issue.